# On a generalization of A113227 as a subsequence of the partial sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

This question is just a generalization of the [one of my previous questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445425/sequence-that-sums-up-to-the-number-of-permutations-avoiding-the-pattern-1-23-4).

Let
$$a(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}u(n,m,k,i)$$
where
$$u(n,m,k,i)=u(n-1,m,k,i-1)+(m-1)(i+k-1)\sum\limits_{j=i}^{n-1}u(n-1,m,k,j), u(n,m,k,0)=[n=0]$$

There are at least two sequences in the OEIS that are special cases of a given sequence family:

- $a(n,2,1)$ - [A113227](https://oeis.org/A113227)
- $a(n,2,2)$ - [A258173](https://oeis.org/A258173)

Let $b(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(m^p(mn+1),m,k)=b(m^p(mn+2),m,k)=\cdots=b(m^p(mn+m-1),m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{p}(j+k)b(m^j n,m,k), b(0, m, k)=1$$

Let $s(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m^n-1}b(j,m,k)$$

I conjecture that for $m\geqslant2$
$$s(n,m,k)=a(n+1,m,k)$$

Here is the PARI prog to verify this conjecture:

```
u(n, m, k, i) = if(i==0, n==0, u(n-1, m, k, i-1) + (m-1)*(i + k - 1)*sum(j=i, n-1, u(n-1, m, k, j)))
a(n, m, k) = sum(i=1, n, u(n, m, k, i))
b(n, m, k) = if(n==0, 1, my(A=valuation(n, m), B=n\m^(A+1)); sum(j=0, A, (j+k)*b(m^j*B, m, k)))
s(n, m, k) = sum(j=0, m^n-1, b(j, m, k))
test(n, m, k) = s(n, m, k)==a(n+1, m, k)
```

Is there a way to prove it?